# Combining Android Room with other flows correctly - Room flow is too slow

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Hi folks I am exploring the Tivi project and implementing much of the functionality but have come across a race condition. Let's say I have a loading state flow, a data-from-Room flow and a messages flow combined to produce ui state:

```
    val uiState = combine(
        loadingState.observable
            .onEach { Log.d("HomeVM", "LOADING $it") },
        observeUserDetails.flow
            .onEach { Log.d("HomeVM", "USER $it") },
        uiMessageManager.message
            .onEach { Log.d("HomeVM", "MESSAGE ${it}") },
    )
    { refreshing, user, message ->
        
        Log.d("HomeVM", "--- EMISSION -- LOADING: $refreshing, USER: ${user}, MESSAGE: ${message}")
        if (refreshing) {
            HomeUiState.Loading
        }
        else if(user != null){
            HomeUiState.Loaded(message)
        }
        else{
            HomeUiState.Error(message)
        }
    }
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
            initialValue = HomeUiState.Loading
        )
```

The user flow is as follows:

```
class ObserveUserDetails @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: UserDataRepository,
) : SubjectInteractor<ObserveUserDetails.Params, User?>() {

    override fun createObservable(params: Params): Flow<User?> {
        return repository
            .observeUser(params.id)
    }

    data class Params(val id: Int)
}
```

```
abstract class SubjectInteractor<P : Any, T> {
    // Ideally this would be buffer = 0, since we use flatMapLatest below, BUT invoke is not
    // suspending. This means that we can't suspend while flatMapLatest cancels any
    // existing flows. The buffer of 1 means that we can use tryEmit() and buffer the value
    // instead, resulting in mostly the same result.
    private val paramState = MutableSharedFlow<P>(
        replay = 1,
        extraBufferCapacity = 1,
        onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST,
    )

    val flow: Flow<T> = paramState
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest { createObservable(it) }
        .distinctUntilChanged()

    operator fun invoke(params: P) {
        paramState.tryEmit(params)
    }

    protected abstract fun createObservable(params: P): Flow<T>
}
```

So in the init block of the view model, I invoke a ObserveUserDetails, and call refresh which sets loading to true, fetches the user from the API, writes him to the db and sets loading to false.

That work is captured in:

```
abstract class Interactor<in P> {
    operator fun invoke(
        params: P,
        timeoutMs: Long = defaultTimeoutMs,
    ): Flow<InvokeStatus> = flow {
        try {
            withTimeout(timeoutMs) {
                emit(InvokeStarted)
                doWork(params)
                emit(InvokeSuccess)
            }
        } catch (t: TimeoutCancellationException) {
            emit(InvokeError(t))
        }
    }.catch { t -> emit(InvokeError(t)) }

    suspend fun executeSync(params: P) = doWork(params)

    protected abstract suspend fun doWork(params: P)

    companion object {
        private val defaultTimeoutMs = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)
    }
}
```

What's happening is:

- The work completes (user retrieved + written to the db)
- Loading is set to false as the work is complete (InvokeSuccess is emitted). This happens *BEFORE* the Room database
  emits the user.
- User is emitted from Room

That means we have a split second where loading is false and no data exists so we briefly see an error screen.

In Tivi, it seems to write to the local database and emit that value every time *before* Loading is set to false. I don't know why this is, possibly some optimization in the Store library being used.

The only solution I have found is to filter the Room flow to only emit when the user is not null, but to `emit(null)` in the user flow's `onStart` so something is there otherwise the combine function is never called. What is the better solution here?

Obviously it should be irrelevant whether or not Room returns first, but putting null into a Flow's `onStart` seems like a hack, I will end up doing it all over my codebase. I've also tried coming up with alternative conditions to show an error screen but can't quite get it.

Comment: `it seems to write to the local database and emit that value every time before Loading is set to false.` I'd say this is partially to avoid an intermediate state where it's "no longer loading, but not yet ready".

Comment: The whole existence of the `uiMessageManager` seems fragile to me, at least at first glance. Are you always sure the latest message in it matches the latest message having to do with the most recent fetch of a User? Since these are two separate flows that you're combining, you will always have brief emissions downstream where the value of the user flow and the message flow will not be in sync yet from the most recent fetch. And could there be other tasks that also publish to this message flow?

Comment: I think I would have just one flow for fetching users. Wrap it in a UI flow that uses a sealed class that can be Loading, Error, or Success(user instance). From what little I'm seeing of your code above, it seems like maybe your encapsulation boundaries are in the wrong dimension, splitting apart closely related tasks instead of breaking up layers of detail. Then having to have to put it back together elsewhere. I'm catching [FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition) vibes from what few classes I'm seeing.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini yes I don't know how it happens but to me it looks like it's by chance. And there is no concept of an error screen in Tivi, it just flashes up and error message and shows nothing if the data is not there

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah it's definitely over engineered, I'm trying to simplify - in fact any ui messages in this case are totally irrelevant. This mechanism keeps the loading condition separate from Room which I suppose is the core problem

Comment: Is this code design from Tivi? I haven't really looked at it. To be fair, I haven't worked on enormous projects, so I don't have experience with the kinds of pitfalls this kind of design might be trying to prevent.

Comment: Well, if I am not mistaken (and I may be) they "recently" (maybe in the last couple of years) were adding "offline" capabilities, so these flows and combines may be part of that. But I also haven't looked into it since before it was ported to Compose UI.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes it's the same classes used in Tivi. It's pretty clever and works well in that app but seems to have this issue. The NowInAndroid sample only loads data via Work Manager so it's no use either.